# How many distinct triangles can be made from circle with N points equally spaced?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How many distinct triangles can be made from circle with N points equally spaced? Where triangles are not distinct when they can be made by rotating or reflecting other triangles.

I started off with some specific cases, specifically 6 points. I did 6 choose 3, and then subtracted the equilateral triangles (2); this results in 18. I then divided by 6 to account for the rotations that can be made which gives me three. And finally I added 1 to account for the one equilateral triangle.

So my final result for a circle points was 4 triangles, however if we take into account reflections the answer is actually 3.

Can someone help with a systematic way to count how many repeated reflections it will have?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: At any $N \geq 3$ there are $\lfloor \frac{N-1}{2}\rfloor$ distinct isosceles triangles (including equilateral at $3|N$). Add number the way of decomposition of $N$ into three distinct natural summands $a>b>c$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001399